# Error erasing old data from logcat

Tags: android

While trying to delete old data form logcat using **adb logcat -c**, I'm facing the following error.

**klogctl: Operation not permitted**.

Can someone please assist?

Note: I want to delete logs that have been generated before the device was connected to the system, crash logs, etc, that can be seen using the command **adb logcat**.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by rooting the device and restarting ADB in root.

Or if you're on a Samsung device, try dialing ***#9900#** into the phone to open the SysDump utility, then select **delete dumpstate/logcat**.

It's a bit of a hassle and doesn't allow you to clear the log in the middle of something, but at least it'll stop the device from barfing everything up each time you run logcat.

If you aren't on a Samsung device, please let me know what device it is. I've only ever seen this happen on Galaxy S3s, and would like to know if it happens elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

for clearing logcat just click on the button right to the save icon.

[image]

Comment: I connected the device, and am trying to delete log data that is already present in the device, not the new one which has been generated after the device was connected to the system.